# Is there a way to loop through a list of objects and then return a value based on an enum value for each object

Tags: java, list, object, enums, return

Im new to java and have a list of objects  named `listAnimal`, here's a sample below:

```
[Animal{name='Atlantic', type='Actinopterygii', scienName='sturio', country='Global', endangerment='Critical Endangerment', popTrend='Decreasing'}, Animal{name='eel', type='Actinopterygii', scienName='Anguilla anguilla', country='Europe', endangerment='Critical Endangerment', popTrend='Decreasing'},
```

i have some enums classes that i would like to use

```
public enum LevelOfEndangerment {
/**
 * an enum to give values to levels of endangerment
 */

EXTINCT(8), NEAR_EXTINCT(7), CRITICAL_ENDANGERMENT(6), ENDANGERED(5), SOMEWHAT_VULNERABLE(4), NEAR_VULNERABLE(3),
NON_CONCERN(2), DATA_DEFICIENT(1), NOT_EVALUATED(0);

private int value;

LevelOfVulnerability (int aValue) {
    this.value = aValue;
}

public int getValue () {
    return value;
}
```

Im struggling to think of ways to loop through `listAnimal` and check the endangerment value in the Animal object details for example "Critical Endangerment" and use the enum to return the value 6 in accordance with its aValue.

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you a method like `LevelOfEndangerment getEndargement()` in your `Animal` class ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have single `Animal` then you can convert `endangerment` string into `ENUM` and get the value

```
String eng = animal.getEndargement();
LevelOfEndangerment engVal = LevelOfEndangerment.valueOf(eng.replace(" ","_").toUpperCase());
Integer value = engVal.getValue();
```

If you have list of `Animal` you can stream and get the value

```
List<Integer> values = listAnimal.stream()
                                 .map(an-> LevelOfEndangerment.valueOf(an.getEndargement().replace(" ","_").toUpperCase())
                                 .map(LevelOfEndangerment::getValue)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: in this second example, where would .getEndangerment values come from?

Comment: It is lambda expression, please check this docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html @user14087442